# getaddrinfo destination address selection logic

Tags: c, glibc

I am trying to load balance across 8 nodes using DNS server. The setup is like I will map a host name , say my.example.com with 8 ip and configure my DNS server with a ttl of 1 for this domain.

The ips are like 10.9.20.31 - 34 and 10.9.20.21 - 24. The expectation is like after every second i will get a new ip ranging from 31-34 and 21-24, while i resolve using getaddrinfo. But i am seeing only 33 and 34 getting resolved and all other ip are not all getting resolved. (ie) the sorting logic of getaddrinfo always prefer 33 and 34.

Is it possible to make getaddrinfo to use all the ips. I went through /etc/gai.conf but not very sure of the setting. Can some one give me inputs to overcome this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the IP address sorting logic is the most important feature of getaddrinfo library function. It works according to RFC3484 and the things which mostly gets in our way is Rule #9 for Destination address selection.

We cant turn that off. But we can configure our IPs is such a way so that this sorting algorithm wont get triggered. One way i did is by having source and destination IPs in different Subnets.